# How to set the security token in breeze to access SharePoint list?

Tags: sharepoint, breeze, token

I have used http://www.andrewconnell.com/blog/getting-breezejs-to-work-with-the-sharepoint-2013-rest-api
code in a empty web application project. How can I set the security access in order to deal with the SharePoint list.

```
function configureBreeze() {
    // configure breeze to use SharePoint OData service
    var dsAdapter = breeze.config.initializeAdapterInstance('dataService', 'SharePointOData', true);
    dsAdapter.defaultSettings = {
        xhrFields: {
            withCredentials: true
        }
    };

    // tell breeze how to get the security validation token for 
    //  HTTP POST & DELETE calls
    dsAdapter.getRequestDigest = function () {
        return jQuery('#__REQUESTDIGEST').val();
    };
}
```

I am getting a Access Denied error!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you look at **all three parts of Andrew's post**?

[**Part 3**](http://www.andrewconnell.com/blog/getting-breezejs-to-work-with-the-sharepoint-2013-rest-api) talks about security ... the "request digest" in particular ... and shows you how to get the SharePoint OData adapter and set the `adapter.getRequestDigest` function.

You might want to post additional questions to that blog post too.